# Hadoop streaming Python Mapper and reducer error message print. Is that possible?

Tags: python, hadoop, error-handling, mapreduce

I am working on a Hadoop streaming job with a python mapper and reducer.
Therefore my command looks like

```
yarn jar /where/hadoop-version/blahblah/hadoop-streaming.jar. -files mapper.py,reducer.py  -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py -input input.txt -output output
```

However, Hadoop streaming doesn't give me a helpful error message when my python code has a problem. For example, if I have any typo in my mapper.py or if my for loop is out of the range of the list. Hadoop just gives me back a java error that I cannot understand.

Is there any technique that shows a python error message?

Answer (score 1):

Any error in a YARN executed application would not be present in your terminal, only a report of the code that was ran.

If you want to see syntax or runtime errors, you must get the logs from the YARN container that actual ran that script, either in the UI or with `yarn log` CLI

Alternatively, if you are mistyping code in your mapper file, then I'd suggest using a better IDE setup and/or unit tests. One alternative would be to use pyspark rather than mapreduce, where you also more clearly see any errors when executing a driver application